# ColdFusion unable to execute ObjectLoad on Linux server with objects

Tags: java, linux, coldfusion, coldfusion-10

Running the following simplified code I am unable to use [`ObjectSave`](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/ColdFusion/9.0/CFMLRef/WSf01dbd23413dda0e613c53881225a218cab-7fff.html) and then immediately [`ObjectLoad`](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/ColdFusion/9.0/CFMLRef/WSf01dbd23413dda0e613c53881225a218cab-8000.html) to get my original object

```
<!--- AbstractModel.cfc --->
<cfcomponent output="false">
  <cffunction name="initAttributes" access="private" returntype="void">
  </cffunction>
</cfcomponent>

<cfset myObj = createObject("component","AbstractModel")>
<cfset myObj = ObjectSave(myObj)>
<cfdump var="#myObj#">
<cftry>
  <cfset myObj = ObjectLoad(myObj)>
  <cfdump var="#myObj#">
  <cfcatch>
    <cfdump var="#cfcatch#">
  </cfcatch>
</cftry>
```

The first dump outputs a binary object, but running `ObjectLoad` throws this error

```
java.util.concurrent.ConcurrentHashMap incompatible with java.util.WeakHashMap
```

StackTrace

```
java.lang.ClassCastException: java.util.concurrent.ConcurrentHashMap incompatible with java.util.WeakHashMap at 
coldfusion.runtime.TemplateProxyWrapper.readResolve(TemplateProxyWrapper.java:80) at 
sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor382.invoke(Unknown Source) at 
sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:37) at 
java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:611) at 
java.io.ObjectStreamClass.invokeReadResolve(ObjectStreamClass.java:1126) at 
java.io.ObjectInputStream.readOrdinaryObject(ObjectInputStream.java:1779) at 
java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject0(ObjectInputStream.java:1346) at 
java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject(ObjectInputStream.java:365) at 
coldfusion.tagext.io.FileUtils.loadInstance(FileUtils.java:1699) at 
coldfusion.runtime.CFPage.ObjectLoad(CFPage.java:8814) at 
cfjunk2ecfm1335312837.runPage(/webdata/data/installedApps/ADCDevDSM.ear/ADCDevDSM.war/pmb046/junk.cfm:6) at 
coldfusion.runtime.CfJspPage.invoke(CfJspPage.java:244) at 
coldfusion.tagext.lang.IncludeTag.doStartTag(IncludeTag.java:444) at 
coldfusion.filter.CfincludeFilter.invoke(CfincludeFilter.java:65) at 
coldfusion.filter.IpFilter.invoke(IpFilter.java:64) at 
coldfusion.filter.ApplicationFilter.invoke(ApplicationFilter.java:449) at 
coldfusion.filter.RequestMonitorFilter.invoke(RequestMonitorFilter.java:48) at 
coldfusion.filter.MonitoringFilter.invoke(MonitoringFilter.java:40) at 
coldfusion.filter.PathFilter.invoke(PathFilter.java:112) at 
coldfusion.filter.ExceptionFilter.invoke(ExceptionFilter.java:94) at 
coldfusion.filter.BrowserDebugFilter.invoke(BrowserDebugFilter.java:79) at 
coldfusion.filter.ClientScopePersistenceFilter.invoke(ClientScopePersistenceFilter.java:28) at 
coldfusion.filter.BrowserFilter.invoke(BrowserFilter.java:38) at 
coldfusion.filter.NoCacheFilter.invoke(NoCacheFilter.java:46) at 
coldfusion.filter.GlobalsFilter.invoke(GlobalsFilter.java:38) at 
coldfusion.filter.DatasourceFilter.invoke(DatasourceFilter.java:22) at 
coldfusion.filter.CachingFilter.invoke(CachingFilter.java:62) at 
coldfusion.CfmServlet.service(CfmServlet.java:219) at 
coldfusion.bootstrap.BootstrapServlet.service(BootstrapServlet.java:89) at 
com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapper.service(ServletWrapper.java:1224) at 
com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapper.handleRequest(ServletWrapper.java:774) at 
com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapper.handleRequest(ServletWrapper.java:456) at 
com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapperImpl.handleRequest(ServletWrapperImpl.java:178) at 
com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.WebAppFilterChain.invokeTarget(WebAppFilterChain.java:136) at 
com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.WebAppFilterChain.doFilter(WebAppFilterChain.java:97) at 
coldfusion.monitor.event.MonitoringServletFilter.doFilter(MonitoringServletFilter.java:42) at 
coldfusion.bootstrap.BootstrapFilter.doFilter(BootstrapFilter.java:46) at 
com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.FilterInstanceWrapper.doFilter(FilterInstanceWrapper.java:191) at 
com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.WebAppFilterChain.doFilter(WebAppFilterChain.java:91) at 
com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.WebAppFilterManager.doFilter(WebAppFilterManager.java:928) at 
com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.WebAppFilterManager.invokeFilters(WebAppFilterManager.java:1025) at 
com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.webapp.WebApp.handleRequest(WebApp.java:3751) at 
com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.webapp.WebGroup.handleRequest(WebGroup.java:304) at 
com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.WebContainer.handleRequest(WebContainer.java:962) at 
com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.WSWebContainer.handleRequest(WSWebContainer.java:1662) at 
com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.channel.WCChannelLink.ready(WCChannelLink.java:195) at 
com.ibm.ws.http.channel.inbound.impl.HttpInboundLink.handleDiscrimination(HttpInboundLink.java:452) at 
com.ibm.ws.http.channel.inbound.impl.HttpInboundLink.handleNewRequest(HttpInboundLink.java:511) at 
com.ibm.ws.http.channel.inbound.impl.HttpInboundLink.processRequest(HttpInboundLink.java:305) at 
com.ibm.ws.http.channel.inbound.impl.HttpICLReadCallback.complete(HttpICLReadCallback.java:83) at 
com.ibm.ws.ssl.channel.impl.SSLReadServiceContext$SSLReadCompletedCallback.complete(SSLReadServiceContext.java:1784) at 
com.ibm.ws.tcp.channel.impl.AioReadCompletionListener.futureCompleted(AioReadCompletionListener.java:165) at 
com.ibm.io.async.AbstractAsyncFuture.invokeCallback(AbstractAsyncFuture.java:217) at 
com.ibm.io.async.AsyncChannelFuture.fireCompletionActions(AsyncChannelFuture.java:161) at 
com.ibm.io.async.AsyncFuture.completed(AsyncFuture.java:138) at 
com.ibm.io.async.ResultHandler.complete(ResultHandler.java:204) at 
com.ibm.io.async.ResultHandler.runEventProcessingLoop(ResultHandler.java:775) at 
com.ibm.io.async.ResultHandler$2.run(ResultHandler.java:905) at 
com.ibm.ws.util.ThreadPool$Worker.run(ThreadPool.java:1690)
```

I'm running ColdFusion Enterprise 10,0,11,285437 on x86 Linux 2.6.32-220.7.1.el6.x86_64 (as reported by the ColdFusion server) on Java 1.6.0

I'm guessing this is a bug in Linux Java as the same code runs successfully in Java 1.6 and 1.7 on Windows and if I use an array, struct or text instead of an object it also works successfully

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried saving and loading it with the filepath argument:

```
<!--- Save the component object to a file. ---> 
<cfset ObjectSave(tellTimeObj, "data.out")/> 

<!--- Load the component object again. --->  
<cfset ObjLoaded = ObjectLoad("data.out") >
```

Comment: I get the same error when outputting it to a file and then reading that file in.

Comment: I've just tested it on same version of CF but on UNIX Linux 3.2.0-23-virtual and it all worked fine. Have you tried restarting CF?

Comment: Were you testing with Java 1.6? The CF service has been restarted a few times.

Comment: No, we're using 1.7.0_15 on all servers now.

Comment: We can't update our java install, but basically boiled this down to a bug in Java 1.6

Comment: Is there a newer version 1.6 you can use?

Comment: @JamesMohler there is not